# How to create *static* property in can.Model

Tags: canjs, canjs-model

I need somehow to store metadata in the can.Model
I use findAll method and receive such JSON:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "color": "red"
    },
    "data": [
        { "id": 1, "description": "Do the dishes." },
        { "id": 2, "description": "Mow the lawn." },
        { "id": 3, "description": "Finish the laundry." }
    ]
}
```

I can work with *data* like can.Model.List, but I need *metadata* like a static property or something.

Comment: Would you like to add a static property to the can.Model.List or would you like all of your model instances to have a color property set to "red"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [can.Model.parseModels](http://canjs.com/docs/can.Model.parseModels.html) to adjust your response JSON before it's turned into a can.Model.List.

```
parseModels: function(response, xhr) {
  var data = response.data;
  var metadata = response.metadata;
  var properties;

  if(data && data.length && metadata) {
    properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(metadata);

    can.each(data, function(datum) {
      can.each(properties, function(property) {
        datum[property] = metadata[property];
      });
    });
  }

  return response;
}
```

Here's a functional example in JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/qoxuju/1/edit?js,console